# C++ how to reveal only one piece of code to user and let them compile

Tags: c++

I have a system built in C++, however I only want to reveal only one piece of my source code to users so that they can modify according to their need. Thing is, they still need the rest of the code to compile. What is a good way to hide these code but still make the whole project able to compile? I have considered translating into unreadable code/ compile each file to .so and give it to them. Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: You can use a scripting language such as Lua, that the user is able to modify, or you can compile your bits to .lib files, and let the user only compile the bits they need.

Comment: it's already done, I don't have the time to translate into Lua again

Comment: Build a library out of the code they should not see.

Comment: Compile your code into DLLs and use pointer-to-implementation idiom. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer In other words, give them your compiled code and your header file. Other than that I don't think there's any way of achieving what you want.

Comment: no, you embed lua into the project then the user can only add lua. the parts in c++ stay in c++, you then get an engine which the end user can adapt using lua scripts.

Comment: Get them to sign a licence agreement?

Comment: If you don't want to embed a scripting language (which is the usual way to handle programmable customer customizations) then yes a library is probably the way to go, perhaps two libraries (one static containing the `main` function, and one dynamic which contains most of your code). You can also use dynamic loading of shared object (`.so`) files, in which case all you have to give the customer is some curated header files needed to create the shared object file.

Comment: Depending on that kind of project this is, you might want *your users* to compile the .lib / .dll and give that to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx for all the answers in discussion section, I ended up compiling every class into .so files, and keep only the one that was needed to be modified in .cpp.